# bootstrap sub theme rendering garland

Tags: theming

I copied the database and source code from my local to another server. 
On my local I have a bootstrap sub theme set as default which works fine. On the other server (which has the exact same db settings and code) the theme being rendered is Garland despite being disabled and the admin section under appearance stating that my sub-theme is the active one.

When I checked the site after updating the server it had the correct css but when I reloaded the page it reverted back to garland but without any changes to the admin settings.

What are some good steps to take in terms of debugging this.

Comment: Clear the caches to start...

Comment: I've done that but because i copied the db from a server that currently works correctly the cache shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Well if you've copied the _cache_ then obviously it will be an issue...

Comment: I don't understand how cache from a correct version would cause issues but either way it's been cleared

Comment: 'Cos cache is transient and can contain references to (amongst other things) absolute paths. Clearing cache is the first thing you should do when moving a site, or even better, don't copy the cache in the first place. If the code and database are genuinely identical, then logically you must have a problem with your web server/database config - make sure those are the same on both machines next

Comment: I understand what you mean about paths but I have a script that changes any references to host names and the directory structure on both servers are identical. I've added some info to the question in case that sparks any other ideas. Thanks for the comments by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the garland theme and re-added it. After this everything worked properly. I don't know why this worked!

Comment: How bizarre! Maybe it was an APC issue or something?

Comment: no apc or any caching etc. The whole thing is in very early stages of development. I usually don't touch drupal so I wouldn't be surprised to find that I had silly mistake but I have found that since installing the bootstrap theme there has been a lot of strange behaviour such as templates not rendering properly and now this